# Using Foreach loop for inserting data into 70 fields long database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 70 text fields in my HTML form. I want to insert data from those fields to the database using php and mysqli. So I thought of using the foreach loop while creating the sql query..I tried the following, but I am not able to get the required result.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$f = $f . "," . $key ;
$v = $v . ",'" . $value . "'";      
}
$sql = "insert into table1($f) values ($v)";
```

The variable`f`is supposed to carry a string of comma seperated field names which are fields of the `$_POST` array. While variable `v` is to carry single quoted comma seperated values of the `$_POST` array. I am getting an extra comma in the starting of `f` and `v` right now. How to remove that.

Please help!

Comment: use `rtrim()` function to remove that extra comma from the right side of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `rtrim()` to remove that extra commas from the right side

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$f = $f . "," . $key ;
$v = $v . ",'" . $value . "'";      
}
$f = rtrim($f,',');
$v = rtrim($v,',');
$sql = "insert into table1($f) values ($v)";
```

`rtrim($f, ",")` would cut trailing commas.

`trim($f, ",")` would cut trailing and prefixing commas.

you can also use `substr()` to **remove last character from string** like below

```
substr($f, 0, -1);
substr($v, 0, -1);
```

> further reading for
>
> `trim()` : http://php.net/trim
>
> `rtrim()` : http://php.net/rtrim
>
> `substr()` : http://php.net/substr

**EDIT**
A better way would be

```
$f = array(); // create blank arrays
$v = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
    $f[] = $key; // push values to the array
    $v[] = $value;      
}
$f1 = implode(",", $f); // convert array to comma separated string
$v1 = implode(",", $v);
$sql = "insert into table1($f1) values ($v1)";
```

let me know if that helped you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$f .= $f . "," . $key ;
$v .= $v . ",'" . $value . "'";      
}
$f = ltrim($f,',');
$v = ltrim($v,',');
$sql = "insert into table1($f) values ($v)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to check first using `isset()` before prefixing comma, this will also remove the warnings you are getting.

```
 foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $f = isset($f) ? $f . "," . $key : $key;
        $v = isset($v) ? $v . "," . $value : $value;
    }
```